# VB Form and MS Access SQL Wildcard Search

Tags: sql, vba, wildcard, ms-access-2010

My table **table1** has 3 fields: **`FName`**, **`LName`**, **`Phone`**. I am using Microsoft Access 2010 for running the SQL query. Some rows has empty / null phone values.

I have a VB form which accepts search parameters. A user can enter **`(FName and LName)`** or **`(Phone)`**, but not both at the same time.

When I try:

`SELECT  table1.LName, table1.FName, table1.Phone
FROM table1
WHERE table1.LName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!LName & '*') AND table1.FName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!FName & '*')
ORDER BY table1.LName, table1.FName;`

It gives me a list of user matching the given (`FName` and `LName`) parameters. It works fine.

Similarly, when I try:

`SELECT  table1.LName, table1.FName, table1.Phone
FROM table1
WHERE table1.Phone Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!Phone & '*')
ORDER BY table1.LName, table1.FName;`

It gives me a list of user matching the given (`Phone`) parameter. It works fine too.

But, when I combine both these queries:

`SELECT  table1.LName, table1.FName, table1.Phone
FROM table1
WHERE table1.Phone Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!Phone & '*') AND table1.LName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!LName & '*') AND table1.FName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!FName & '*')
ORDER BY table1.LName, table1.FName;`

It doesn't give me the expected results.

I even tried `OR` condition between (`FName` and `LName`) and (`Phone`) search parameters. It doesn't work. I have tried `nz(frmSearchMain!Phone,"")` for all the search params, `%` instead of `*`, but no luck so far.

I am new to the MS Access SQL Query format. I have used this type of queries a lot of times in MySQL. But I couldn't get the expected results from this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some test data would be helpful.

Comment: If you're still working at this, I suggest running these queries in a standard query in access. The debugger/compiler from that should give you some hints as to what's going on. Once you get the query working, you can look into the syntax of VBA for your specific use. Or perhaps use that query through VBA (would be much cleaner)

Comment: Thanks StuckAtWork. I will try that today.

Comment: @StuckAtWork: The problem was in my query. I didn check the null values in the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be easier to sort this one out if we simplify it.  So I arbitrarily decided to ignore `LName` for now, and do the searching based only on `FName` or `Phone`.

In my version of `frmSearchMain`, I named the text box which holds the search target value for `FName` as `txtSearchFName` simply because I prefer to name the control differently than the record source field.  Similarly, I chose `txtSearchPhone` for the `Phone` search target text box.

Since I already had a table named `Table1`, I called mine `tblKeerthiram` instead.

With those changes, this query gives me rows which match `txtSearchFName` or `txtSearchPhone`.  If both `txtSearchFName` and `txtSearchPhone` are Null, the query return all rows from the table ... which is what I hope you want.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.FName,
    t1.Phone
FROM tblKeerthiram AS t1
WHERE
           (t1.FName Like "*"
               & [Forms]![frmSearchMain]![txtSearchFName]
               & "*"
        OR [Forms]![frmSearchMain]![txtSearchFName] Is Null)
    AND
           (t1.Phone Like "*"
               & [Forms]![frmSearchMain]![txtSearchPhone]
               & "*"
        OR [Forms]![frmSearchMain]![txtSearchPhone] Is Null)
ORDER BY t1.FName;
```

A consequence of this approach is that, if both `txtSearchFName` and `txtSearchPhone` are non-Null, the query will return only the rows which match both.  As I understood your description, that is not what you want.  You want to search by only one or the other, not both at the same time.

In that case I suggest you use the after update events for the two search text boxes to set the other Null when a non-Null value has been entered into one of them.  I'm unsure how clear that sentence was, so just add this code to your form's module.  It will ensure that only one of the two text boxes will contain a non-Null value.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub txtSearchFName_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchFName) Then
        Me.txtSearchPhone = Null
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearchPhone_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchPhone) Then
        Me.txtSearchFName = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally if that all works, then you only need to revise it to deal with `LName`.  Hope that part won't be too daunting.  Good luck.

Comment: Your query did the trick. I just added the Null check for all the text boxes. Thx HansUp

Answer (score 0):

In your example this query give the result for a record that match all the 3 conditions:

```
SELECT table1.LName, table1.FName, table1.Phone FROM table1 WHERE table1.Phone Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!Phone & '*') AND table1.LName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!LName & '*') AND table1.FName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!FName & '*') ORDER BY table1.LName, table1.FName;
```

If you want return the records that match (Phone) OR (FName AND LName) you have to do this:

```
SELECT table1.LName, table1.FName, table1.Phone FROM table1
WHERE  (table1.Phone Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!Phone & '*'))
OR (table1.LName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!LName & '*') AND table1.FName Like ('*' & Forms!frmSearchMain!FName & '*'))
ORDER BY table1.LName, table1.FName;
```

Hope it help

Comment: I tried the "OR" condition between the Phone and (FName and LName). It didn work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "SELECT LName, FName, Phone" & _
      "FROM table1" & _
      "WHERE (" & _
      "Phone LIKE ('%" & Forms!frmSearchMain!Phone & "%' )" & _
      "OR ( FName LIKE ('%" & Forms!frmSearchMain!FName & "%' )" & _
            "AND LName LIKE ('%" & Forms!frmSearchMain!LName & "%' ) )" & _
      "ORDER BY LName, FName"
```

Running that query should return all LName, FName, Phone which have the correct first AND last name, or the correct phone (or both).

Note: paraphrase that, I honestly don't know how to properly concatenate those multi-line VBA strings.

Comment: ops same answer as mine except the wildcard that in MS Access mus be `*` but Keerthiram Murugesan said didnt work... strange

Comment: I wasn't 100% on the wildcard.. I know the query objects ask for % (for example, one of my queries contains `ALIKE "12 - %"` and works properly), it may be different in VBA.