# How to use applyfilter in Microsoft Access to allow user input to equal any part of an existing form field?

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a search form in Microsoft Access 2013.  I am using the ApplyFilter action to show items that match user input.  I want the user input box to match any part of the form field.

So far I have the search form working but the form only shows items that match what the user has inputed exactly.  If a user types "potato" in the input field and clicks the search button, the results only show "potato" and not "potato salad", "potato chips" and so on.

My action is:

Apply Filter

```
Filter Name:Subject
Where Condition =:="Subject = '" & [Forms]![frmTaskerTable]![txtSubject] & "'"
Control Name:
```

The form field the results are coming from is "Subject".  The user input box is located in the form "frmTaskerTable" and is named "txtSubject".

I would like for the results to show all results that match any part of the text the user inputs.

Comment: Use LIKE and * wildcard. I have never used ApplyFilter. I set Filter and FilterOn properties. Also prefer VBA to macros. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB Form and MS Access SQL Wildcard Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889435/vb-form-and-ms-access-sql-wildcard-search)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Subject LIKE '*" & [Forms]![frmTaskerTable]![txtSubject] & "*'"
```